# Toggle visibility of features in FeatureLayer

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-10.1, feature-service, feature-layer

How to toggle the visibility of features in a feature-layer using check-boxes. I have grid containing check-boxes in a columns representing each feature in Feature-layer and so if I check off the check-box I can turn off the visibility and if I check in turn on the visibility using ArcGIS JavaScript API 3.1.

Comment: Are you using a feature service with a renderer or a map service?

Comment: Feature service @ blord-castillo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Selection mode for the feature layer. Set your symbol using Layer.setSelectionSymbol(symbol). If you have a complex symbology, set the renderer instead and leave the selection symbol blank.

There are two ways to go about the next part.

**Method one:**

Use the checkboxes to composite a complex query. For example, if each feature has a unique identifier (call it IID), then you query will be:

```
IID IN (<List of IDs>)
```

Where the list of IDs is built from all the checked check boxes. jQuery can be very effective in building this list.
Whenever a checkbox is updated, you want to execute

```
Layer.selectFeatures(IID IN (<List of IDs>),esri.layers.FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW)
```

**Method two:**

Use simple queries to add and remove each feature individually as boxes are checked or unchecked.
When a checkbox is checked, you use:

```
Layer.selectFeatures(IID = '<UniqueID>',esri.layers.FeatureLayer.SELECTION_ADD)
```

When a checkbox is unchecked, you use:

```
Layer.selectFeatures(IID = '<UniqueID>',esri.layers.FeatureLayer.SELECTION_SUBTRACT)
```

As you add features to the current selection (or create a new selection) those features will be displayed. As you remove them, they will be hidden. Since selectFeatures() will execute client side if possible, this actually operates very quickly.

Comment: I know this is old but do you still have an example of an application that is using the check boxes to toggle individual features? I am looking for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples/map_explicitlayerlist.html) from ESRI. It sounds like exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: It is switching visibility of entire layer.I want to switch on and off visibility of features in feature Layer.Thanks @Craig